# Voltar para a pagina anterior definindo uma variable

Tags: php, javascript

Eu gostava de fazer o seguinte

```
  echo "<script>window.history.back()</script>";
```

isto faz voltar para a pagina anterior

o que eu pretendia era voltar para a pagina anterior mas defenindo uma variável

imaginamos que a pagina anterior é exemplo.php

eu queria que fizesse "exemplo.php?a=1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obter o url anterior:

```
document.referrer
```

Para redirecionar para o url anterior com parametros adicionais:

```
window.location.href = document.referrer+ '?a=1';
```

Comment: com a window.history.back() o browser mantinha os campos dos formulários ja antes preenchidos  nao da para fazer o mesmo com este :(

Comment: Não, assim você vai fazer um novo request :/ ... De qualquer maneira pode guardar em, por ex: `$_SESSION['campos_form']['username'], $_SESSION['campos_form']['email']` etc... E assim não perde os dados